# Performance Considerations for Firebase Path as ref or key

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As a matter of performance, are there any considerations when setting the path as a ref or in the key (as it relates to 'update' specifically)?

What I mean, is this:

```js
admin.database().ref().update({
    ['root/child/child/key']: 'value'
});
```

vs

```js
admin.database().ref('root/child/child').update({
    key: 'value'
});
```

I am guessing this is splitting hairs, but it seems every time I figure something out (assume something) with Firebase, I end up being wrong.

I know the first example is needed for atomic, multi-location updates (which are fantastic), but if I am just updating one, specific key, does it matter which format is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my outside perspective, there wouldn't be any meaningful difference between the two approaches where most of the latency experienced is instead influenced by your server's network connection.

For small numbers of updated keys, there will be no discernible difference. However, the difference does become more apparent when updating a whole bunch of keys that are all nested under "root/child/child".

The below code sample writes 100k keys to the database at once. Based on its output, for small updates, the difference is negligible. For 1000-10000 records, the difference is about 10%, in favour of updating by keys on a nested reference. For 10000+ records, the difference is about 20-25%, still in favour of updating by keys on a nested reference.

```
// modern client SDK
import { getDatabase, ref, remove, update } from "firebase/database";
import { getFirestore, collection, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

const samples = 100000,
  rtdb = getDatabase(),
  fsdb = getFirestore(),
  idColRef = collection(fsdb, "sample"),
  getPushKey = () => doc(idColRef).id; // using Firestore IDs for more randomness

const runTest = async (testRef, updates) => {
  await remove(ref(rtdb, "root/child/child"));
  console.time("update");
  await update(testRef, updates);
  console.timeEnd("update");
}

const updatesByPath = Object
  .fromEntries(
    Array
      .from({ length: samples })
      .map(() => ["root/child/child/" + getPushKey(), "sample"])
  );
const updatesByKey = Object
  .fromEntries(
    Array
      .from({ length: samples })
      .map(() => [getPushKey(), "sample"])
  );

Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => runTest(ref(rtdb), updatesByPath)) // ~13s on my connection
  .then(() => runTest(ref(rtdb, "root/child/child"), updatesByKey)); // ~10.2s on my connection
  .then(() => remove(ref(rtdb, "root/child/child")));
```

**Note:** These are the results from my browser, your results may vary.

| Sample Size | By Path | By Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 210ms | 211ms |
| 100 | 246ms | 237ms |
| 1000 | 337ms | 295ms |
| 10000 | 1.39s | 1.08s |
| 100000 | 12.58s | 9.87s |

Comment: Thanks for that breakdown. Just what I needed to see (and I am not sure why I didn't think to run it like that). Definitely confirmed what I was thinking.